# Spell checker in android

Tags: android-layout, dictionary, android

I want to create an application in which it checks if the word typed by user is correct or not using Google Dictionary ?
i have used the below [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spelling_checker.htm) . But the problem with the given example is that it suggests the different words. I don't want suggestion, instead i want to only check that word entered is correct or not.

Comment: well this is how [Spelling Checker Framework Works](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html), i suggest you to `onGetSuggestions()` and then match it with your string, like if there is no suggestions/ suggestions contains your string then it means its correct if there are suggestions then its wrong.

Comment: But if i am entering correct word then also it is showing suggestion.For example if i write height then also it gives me suggestion ......

Comment: yes but the suggestions will have `height` in suggestions, which means that your string-height is correctly spelled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked on it yet. But you can probably modify it as:

When you get the suggestions, instead of appending them to StringBuilder, and showing that StringBuilder to MainView, just compare all suggestions with your input string of edittext.

If it matches, then the spell is correct, else the spell is incorrect.

Code snippet:

```
@Override
public void onGetSuggestions(final SuggestionsInfo[] arg0) {
    isSpellCorrect = false;
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < arg0.length; ++i) {
        // Returned suggestions are contained in SuggestionsInfo
        final int len = arg0[i].getSuggestionsCount();
        if(editText1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(arg0[i].getSuggestionAt(j))
        {
            isSpellCorrect = true;
            break;
        }               
     }        
 }
```

Hope this helps.